# How fix position element so that while hovering on one element other two element should remain at same place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create on hover effect shown in below  first two images

[image]

[image]

in below  two images  shows how i have implemented with help of example given on this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243115/how-to-create-special-type-on-hover-effect?noredirect=1#comment39327341_25243115)

[image]

[image]

As you can see while hovering on one image  3rd image position is getting changed ,

How to make two images position fixed while hovering on one image?as displayed on above first two image

here is my jsfiddle [code](http://jsfiddle.net/dhruvin/8p9hu6hd/1/)

css

```
.wrap{
    width:1360px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}
.con{
    display:inline-block;
    width:453px;
    height:453px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(images/new-psd_22.jpg) no-repeat;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-left:#FFF 1px solid;


}
.hover{
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
   width:453px;
    height:453px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition:0.5s;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
     display:inline-block;
}
.con:hover{

      text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:10;
  background:url(images/Indian_Air_Forc17992.jpg) no-repeat;
    height:400px;
    width:570px;
    margin:0px;
}
.con:hover span{

      text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0;
  background:url(images/Indian_Air_Forc17992.jpg) no-repeat;
    height:400px;
    width:570px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

body

```
<ul class="wrap">
<li class="con" style=" float:left;" >
    <span class="hover"  >Hover Me</span>
</li>
    <li class="con"  style=" float:left;" >
    <span class="hover" >Hover Me</span>
</li>

 <li class="con" style=" float:left;" >
    <span class="hover" >Hover Me</span>
</li>

<ul>
```

Comment: Your main problem is, you are changing your elements width and height on HOVER.. so everything else move around.. if you expect for things to stay in place when hovering, do not change their size.

Comment: is this the direction you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/8p9hu6hd/12/

Comment: nope buddy.image should became big and small but the white space between image that i dont want.

Comment: can u visit this"http://invisiblechildren.com/" webpage and help me how that effect is create.

Comment: I don't have the time to explain why I wouldn't do it the way they do it.. (it doesn't work very well, kind of choppy).. but here's a starting point using background images for ya -> http://jsfiddle.net/8p9hu6hd/16/ .. good luck!

Comment: thank bro to give ur time to my answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If older browser support is not an issue, you can use CSS3 flex box.

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
  html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  list-style-type:none;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.con{
  position:relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  flex:1 .5;
  background:url(images/new-psd_22.jpg) no-repeat;
  opacity:0.5;
  margin:0px;
  border-left:#FFF 1px solid;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.hover{
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition:0.5s;
}
.con:hover{
  flex-grow:1.5;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  opacity:10;
  background:url(images/Indian_Air_Forc17992.jpg) no-repeat;
  margin:0px;
}
.con:hover span{
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  opacity:0;
  background:url(images/Indian_Air_Forc17992.jpg) no-repeat;
  margin:0px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8p9hu6hd/14/)

Comment: @user26697 glad it helped… you can read more about flex layout [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)… might come in handy :)

Comment: and bro if i am have different image in different block then how to display that??

Answer (score 0):

Update your `.wrap` class like below. Also remove unwanted `float:left` on style.

```
.wrap{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/8p9hu6hd/5/)

Comment: thank thats working but i done want any space inbetween this images. so can i get some solution about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just give `ul` more width (i added additional 1000px). You can add wrapper with `overflow: hidden;`. Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/8p9hu6hd/4/).

Comment: thanks for your answer but thats not the right solution.