# How to create onhover effect for different images useing display:flex;?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is an extension of my previous question described on this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258415/how-fix-position-element-so-that-while-hovering-on-one-element-other-two-element)

From the given solution i am able to get on hover effect. but the problem is i m not able to give different image to different . Can anyone suggest me some solution!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you mean you just need to give different backgrounds for different `<li>`? or something else..?

Comment: ya i want to show three different image in three different <li>.

Comment: You can try CSS3 filter http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

- Give specific `id`'s to each `<li>`

  for eg, let's say you apply `id`'s first, second and third respectively for the `<li>`'s You can add the background as follows:

  ```
  #first{
     background: url("/path-to-image");
  }
  #second{
     background: url("/path-to-image");
  }
  #third{
     background: url("/path-to-image");
  }
  ```
- Use different classes (*i prefer `id`'s since classes are meant to be used to group elements*)
- Use CSS pseudo selectors.

  ```
  .wrap li:nth-child(1){
     background: url("/path-to-image");
  }
  .wrap li:nth-child(2){
     background: url("/path-to-image");
  }
  .wrap li:nth-child(3){
     background: url("/path-to-image");
  }
  ```

like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8p9hu6hd/17/)

Comment: so by this i can change image on hover too??

Comment: Yea you can use `.wrap li:nth-child(3):hover{
   background: url("/path-to-another-image");
}`